# how to chrome extension background's data to javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background, send

i am working on chrome extension. my project have index.html, index.js and background.js.

> "content_scripts": [
>       {"js": [ "index.html" ],
>    ],
>
> "background": {
>        "scripts":["background.js"],
>    }

when index.js call **window.open(url)**, backgrund.js catch new url
like below

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {          
     if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
          alert(tab.url);
 }});
```

so i want to pass tab.url to index.js's function(whatever)
is it possible ? how can i call it ?

if you know how-to or reference-page

plz Answer, have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To do what you want, tou'll need to use message passing between your extension components.**

First of all, you'll need to add the `tabs` permission to your `manifest.json`. I also spotted some errors in your `manifest.json`, check it out, what you want is something like this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Extension name",
    "description": "Your description...",
    "version": "1",

    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
    ],

    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] }

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content_script.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, in your `background.js`, you'll send a message to your `content_script.js`, like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {          
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {message: "do something", url: tab.url});
    }
});
```

In your `content_script.js` you'll listen to that message and behave consequently:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message === "do something") {
        alert('Got the url:', request.url); // here is the url you sent from background.js
        // do what you want
    }
});
```

---

Here is the [**documentation link**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use messages between the content script and the background script:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging